# Cannot send form data as 'Multipart/formdata'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-router

Cannot send form data as 'Multipart/formdata' Content type in react-native expo app.
when we send formData object in post request in react -native app, we cant get req.body of req.files from node backend

```
  export const saveUserAddVisitor = async data => {
  try {
    const apiUrl = configConstants.apiUrlWithPort;
    const addVisitorData = await axios.post(
      `${apiUrl}/api/v1/mobile/apartment/member`,
      data,
      {
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        },
      },
    );
    return addVisitorData;
  } catch (err) {
    return err;
  }
};
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this which works without Axios:

```
export const saveUserAddVisitor = async data => {
    var data = new FormData()
    data.append('foo', {
        ...
    })
    try {
        const apiUrl = configConstants.apiUrlWithPort;
        const addVisitorData = await fetch(`${apiUrl}/api/v1/mobile/apartment/member`, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                Accept: 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
            },
            body: data
        })
        return addVisitorData;
    } catch {
        return err;
    }
}
```

After I gave you an example of working code for the client, but the problem may be from the server ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your code with axios look like fine, just be sure to send FormData type, like Rémi said here https://stackoverflow.com/a/72454168/16205278

You can construct your `FormData` before this function and use it directly in your current code with your axios function.

**Service :**

```js
import axios from "axios";
import configConstants from "./config.js";

/**
 * Current function to save User Add Visitor
 * @param {*} data
 */
export const saveUserAddVisitor = async (data) => {
  try {
    const apiUrl = configConstants.apiUrlWithPort;
    const addVisitorData = await axios.post(
      `${apiUrl}/api/v1/mobile/apartment/member`,
      data,
      {
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
        }
      }
    );
    return addVisitorData;
  } catch (err) {
    return err;
  }
};
```

**Use** :

```js
import {saveUserAddVisitor} from "./index"

const form = new FormData();
form.append("visitor", { firstName: "Jack", lastName: "Doe" });
saveUserAddVisitor(form);
```

**API Express :**

Apparently, express can't resolve multipart-form data unless some help, according following ressource : https://codex.so/handling-any-post-data-in-express

You have to use `multer` middleware :

```js
const multer = require('multer');

app.post('/', multer().none(), function (req, res, next) {
  req.body;
  //... some code
});
```